# Disable rotation of SKNode in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a player so with a physics body as a circle. 
Think of it as having a flappy bird as `SKNode` with a circle as physics body. Now every time I apply an impulse I want the physics body to rotate but I want do not want the bird to rotate

---

I am using `physicsbody.allowrotation = true` but this rotates the node (bird) as well. I want the bird to not rotate but the physics body should rotate.

Comment: Are you having the bird as a child node to the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably add `SKConstraint` to your `SKSpriteNode` limiting rotation.

```
let birdSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bird.png")
birdSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: max(birdSprite.size.width / 2, birdSprite.size.height / 2))
birdSprite.physicsBody.allowsRotation =  true
birdSprite.constraints = [SKConstraint.zRotation(SKRange(lowerLimit:0 upperLimit:0))]
```